# How to use Django URL field?

Tags: python, html, django

I have an URL field in Django to which I am adding the URL of a photo, how can I render this image to the frontend of my website.

models.py file code for reference

```
class Place(models.Model):
  place_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
  place_photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
  place_photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
  place_photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
  place_photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
  field_name = models.URLField(max_length=500,default='add photo url')

  def __str__(self):
    return self.place_title
```

This is my template.html code

```
                             <div class="placebox-overlap-wrapper">
                                <div class="overlap-box">
                                    <div class="overlap-btns-area">
                                        <div class="car-magnify-gallery">
                                            <a href="{{place.place_photo.url}}" class="overlap-btn">
                                                <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
                                                <img class="hidden" src="{{place.place_photo.url}}">
                                            </a>
                                            {% if place.place_photo_1 %}
                                            <a href="{{place.place_photo_1.url}}" class="hidden"
                                                data-sub-html="<h4>{{place.place_title}}</h4><p>{{place.story1}}</p>">
                                                <img class="hidden" src="{{place.place_photo_1.url}}">
                                            </a>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if place.place_photo_2 %}
                                            <a href="{{place.place_photo_2.url}}" class="hidden"
                                                data-sub-html="<h4>{{place.place_title}}</h4><p>{{place.story2}}</p>">
                                                <img class="hidden" src="{{place.place_photo_2.url}}">
                                            </a>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if place.place_photo_3 %}
                                            <a href="{{place.place_photo_3.url}}" class="hidden"
                                                data-sub-html="<h4>{{place.place_title}}</h4><p>{{place.story3}}</p>">
                                                <img class="hidden" src="{{place.place_photo_3.url}}">
                                            </a>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if place.place_photo_4 %}
                                            <a href="{{place.place_photo_4.url}}" class="hidden"
                                                data-sub-html="<h4>{{place.place_title}}</h4><p>{{place.story4}}</p>">
                                                <img class="hidden" src="{{place.place_photo_4.url}}">
                                            </a>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if place.place_photo_5 %}
                                            <a href="{{place.place_photo_5.url}}" class="hidden"
                                                data-sub-html="<h4>{{place.place_title}}</h4><p>{{place.story5}}</p>">
                                                <img class="hidden" src="{{place.place_photo_5.url}}">
                                            </a>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if place.field_name %}
                                            <a href="{{place.field_name}}" class="hidden"
                                                data-sub-html="<h4>{{place.place_title}}</h4><p>{{place.story5}}</p>">
                                                <img class="hidden" src="{{place.field_name}}">
                                            </a>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

This is my: [Admin file reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FifX0.png)

Showing 5 images to the frontend: [frontend part of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOrAn.jpg)

Problem part : [Not showing URL part image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEzJH.png)

This is my view.py

```
def place(request):
  places = Place.objects.order_by('-added_date')
  paginator = Paginator(places,9)
  page = request.GET.get('page')
  paged_places = paginator.get_page(page)
  country_search = Place.objects.values_list('country',flat=True).distinct()
  location_search = Place.objects.values_list('location',flat=True).distinct()
  architecture_search = Place.objects.values_list('architecture',flat=True).distinct()
  data = {
      'places': paged_places,
      'country_search':country_search,
      'location_search': location_search,
      'architecture_search': architecture_search,
  }
  return render(request,'place/place.html',data)
```

**I am new to Django, so if I am doing any mistake then please help me out. It would be really appreciable**

Comment: Please do not upload images of code / errors, [edit] your question and post them as text formatted as code. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Okay, I noted. Thanks, Abdul for pointing it out!

Comment: So you mean, You want to access an `image` from the `Url` ?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the URL of the image rather to manually upload it from the admin panel and want to show that image to the frontend of my website.

Comment: As I am new to Django. So, if there any other method for doing this then please suggest it. It would be really appreciable.

Comment: Is it showing if you `render any kind of image from url in template` ? ( without using **url field** )

Comment: No, only those images rendered which are uploaded manually but I need to render images using its URLs. I have attached screenshots above for the same. You can view it "Frontend part of the website"